# Creating new object with .net Core Dependency Injection fails with missing parameter error

Tags: dependency-injection, .net-core

I'm trying to new-up an object and if that object's constructor contains a .Net Core-injected dependency (Serilog.ILogger) I get a compile error that "There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter ...".

I can add the ILogger injection in my MVC controller constructor and I get an instance of ILogger so I know the DI is working.

But if I setup a class:

```
using Serilog;

public class TestObject
{
    public TestObject(ILogger logger) { }
}
```

And call it:

```
TestObject test = new TestObject();
```

I get the error message:

> There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'logger' of 'TestObject.TestObject(ILogger)'

(However, injection DOES work in my CommandHandlers, for example, if the handler class is invoked by the MediatR mediator.)

Isn't the whole point of DI so that I don't have to pass in dependencies like this?:

```
var query = new GetAllUsers(logger);
```

If I want to use logging in my commands and queries am I going to have to create factories for all of my command and queries?

Am I missing something fundamental here?

Thank you in advance. It was surprisingly hard to get an answer via Google for this as the keywords "new", "dependency injection", etc. were too common.

Comment: You need to pass a value for the logger parameter. Create a LoggerFactory and have it create a logger for the TestObject class and then pass it in the constructor of TestObject.

Comment: Bummer, I was hoping to avoid that. :) I assume of course that I could just pass the instance that was injected into my controller along to the TestObject class. Thanks for the quick reply.